# How to paginate Laravel 5.3 database Notifications

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

We know that Notifications in Laravel 5.3 can sent via many channels and can store in database.

And we know that can fetch all notifications of a User and show them like this :

```
 $user = App\User::find(1);

foreach ($user->notifications as $notification) {
    echo $notification->type;
}
```

But Suppose case that I have a AllNotifications page that show all notifications of a user and I want to paginate that.

Is there any way to paginate notifications ?

**Update:**
According to [**themsaid** answer on github](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/15315#issuecomment-245195019) I tried the code :

> You can use $user->notifications()->paginate(), the
>   HasDatabaseNotifications trait has a regular morphMany relationship.

First problem is solved But another problem is occured.

I have three notif and used `$user->notifications()->paginate(2)`, then pages links show on the first page but it does not show in the second page and in this case I could not navigate to other pages. why?

**Note:** I found that above problem is not in **Laravel 5.3.4** But there is in **5.3.6**

Comment: How are you displaying the notifications perchance?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$page = 2; /* Actual page */

$limit = 4; /* Limit per page*/

\Auth::user()->notifications()->offset($page*$limit)->limit($limit)->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

I try this in V 5.5.* it work for me:

```
$perpage =  $request->input('perpage', 15);

$page =  $request->input('page', 1);

return $user->notifications()->paginate($perpage, ['*'], 'page', $page);
```

Result:

```
"data": [],
"links": {
    "first": "http://domain.test/notification?page=1",
    "last": "http://domain.test/notification?page=2",
    "prev": "http://domain.test/notification?page=1",
    "next": null
},
"meta": {
    "current_page": 2,
    "from": 4,
    "last_page": 2,
    "path": "http://domain.test/notification",
    "per_page": "3",
    "to": 4,
    "total": 4,
}
```

Extra: if you want to add Unread [Eloquent: API Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-resources%22Eloquent:%20API%20Resources%22)

```
$notification = $user->notifications()->paginate($perpage, ['*'], 'page', $page);

return NotificationResource::collection($notification)->additional(['meta' => [
                                    'unread' => $user->unReadNotifications->count(),
                                ]]);
```

Result:

```
"data": [],
"links": {},
{
    "meta": {
    "current_page": 2,
    "from": 4,
    "last_page": 2,
    "path": "http://domain.test/notification",
    "per_page": "3",
    "to": 4,
    "total": 4,
    "unread": 4 // here
}
```